# Simple Qt app doesn't open on Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

## Environment

- Mac OSX Yosemite
- Qt5
- 3 files

  - main.cpp
  - main.qml
  - webengine.pro

## main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml/QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWebEngine/qtwebengineglobal.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
  QtWebEngine::initialize();

  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl("main.qml"));

  return app.exec();
}
```

## main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Test")
    width: 1200
    height: 800
    visible: true

    WebEngineView {
      width: Screen.width
      height: Screen.height
      anchors.fill: parent
      url: 'http://duckduckgo.com'
    }  
}
```

## webengine.pro

```
TARGET = browser
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES = main.cpp
QT += qml quick webengine
```

## Running QML - `PASS`

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.0/bin/qmlscene main.qml
```

[image]

## Compiling and running Mac App - `FAIL`

```
qmake
make
```

then I clicked on `browser.app`, the application starts but no window opened.

Any hint about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the file **main.qml** is not found. You should get an error message "... File not found" in the console.

To solve this problem either supply a valid path on your drive or use Qt's resource management.
This is documented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html#managing-resource-files-with-the-qt-resource-system), I'll outline the steps:

1) Create file **test.qrc** with the following contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>main.qml</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

2) Add **test.qrc** to **webengine.pro**

```
RESOURCES += test.qrc
```

3) Modify **main.cpp** to load the qml file from the resources:

```
engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
```